# ramda findIndex with gaps

Tags: ramda.js

I have the following code where I want to fill in the `id`, so I'm thinking to write something like this:

```
const data = [
 { id: 'some-id' },
 { id: 'some-other-id' },
 { id: 'third-id' },
];

const tabIndex = R.findIndex(R.propEq('id', R.__))(data);
```

So I can use it like this `tabIndex('third-id')`, but this is not a function. 
What do I miss or confuse with this?

The following works

```
const tabIndex = (id) => R.findIndex(R.propEq('id', id))(data);
```

But I thought, that is the point of `R.__` gaps function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that by far the simplest way to do this is

```
const matchId = (id, data) => R.findIndex(R.propEq('id', id), data);
matchId('third-id', data); //=> 2
```

If you really want to make this points-free, Ramda offers several functions to help, such as [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) and [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) (for which one can often substitute [`lift`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift).)  This one would take `useWith`:

```
const matchId = R.useWith(findIndex, [R.propEq('id'), R.identity]);
matchId('third-id', data); //=> 3
```

But I find the first version much more readable.  You can find both on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%7B%20id%3A%20%27some-id%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%20id%3A%20%27some-other-id%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%20id%3A%20%27third-id%27%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20const%20matchId%20%3D%20%28id%2C%20data%29%20%3D%3E%20R.findIndex%28R.propEq%28%27id%27%2C%20id%29%2C%20data%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20or%0Aconst%20matchId%20%3D%20R.useWith%28findIndex%2C%20%5BR.propEq%28%27id%27%29%2C%20R.identity%5D%29%3B%0A%0AmatchId%28%27third-id%27%2C%20data%29)**.

---

Do pay attention to the [**side note** from Emissary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44368656/1243641).  The `R.__` placeholder is essentially used to show gaps *between* the arguments you supply; as a final argument it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still trying to master this dark art myself but I think the issue is that `R.findIndex` expects a predicate (a function / assertion) as an argument and does not differentiate between predicates and regular curried functions as input.

To resolve this a new function can be composed (evaluated right to left):

```js
const data = [
    { id: 'some-id' },
    { id: 'some-other-id' },
    { id: 'third-id' }
];

const tabIndex = R.compose(R.findIndex(R.__, data), R.propEq('id'));

console.log(tabIndex('third-id')); // 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

**Side Note:** the `R.__` placeholder is inferred automatically for missing right-most arguments - e.g. `R.propEq('id')` and `R.propEq('id', R.__)` are equivalent.

Comment: `findIndex` knows nothing about functors; it only works with lists (really just dense arrays).  The issue is in getting the arguments into the right place to be called appropriately for `findIndex` and `propEq`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for the clarification - wrong terminology aside, I still think there's something to what I'm saying about functions intended as arguments, is there some "functional" reason why and I'm just lacking the vocabulary or maybe just something that hasn't been implemented yet?

Comment: The thing about functions used as arguments is that they have to have the right signature.  So `findIndex` has type `:: (a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> Number.`  And in this case `a` just represents Object.  So the predicate passed to `findIndex` must have type `:: Object -> Boolean`.  But `propEq` has type `:: String -> b -> Object -> Boolean`.  Before we pass our `propEq` function to `findIndex`, we must partially apply the `String` and `b` properties, to be left with an `:: Object -> Boolean` function.  We can do that as you suggest here or with either version in my answer. (1/2)

Comment: In any of those version, `'id'` and `'third-id'` are passed to `propEq` before the resulting function is passed to `findIndex`.  So long as you manage to do that, you should be able to get this to work. (2/2)